# How to find (Debian/Ubuntu/...) packages that provide required Perl modules

Tags: perl, debian, package-managers

I found that installing native Debian or Ubuntu Perl packages, such is often more reliable and convenient than "manually" installing Perl modules via `cpanm` (especially for XS-Modules). Is there an easy way to find these modules given a list of required Perl modules? The most convenient way would be to map a [cpanfile](https://metacpan.org/pod/cpanfile), such as

```
requires 'XML::LibXSLT', '1.78';
```

to a list of distributions and packages that provide the modules for different target platforms:

```
XML::LibXSLT, Ubuntu 13.04, libxml-libxslt-perl, 1.78
XML::LibXSLT, Ubuntu 13.10, libxml-libxslt-perl, 1.78
XML::LibXSLT, Ubuntu 14.04, libxml-libxslt-perl, 1.84
XML::LibXSLT, Debian squeeze, libxml-libxslt-perl, 1.70
XML::LibXSLT, Debian wheezy, libxml-libxslt-perl, 1.77
XML::LibXSLT, Debian jessie, libxml-libxslt-perl, 1.92
XML::LibXSLT, Debian sid, libxml-libxslt-perl, 1.92
```

P.S.: I guess the information can somehow be looked up from the package repositories of each distribution, e.g. http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and https://packages.debian.org but is there a scriptable solution that already does this lookup?

Comment: [Debian::Apt::PM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Debian::Apt::PM)

Comment: @Biffen: looks great but seems to be in a bad shape - so far, I have not managed to get it installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Debian-based systems, install the `dh-make-perl` package and try

```
dh-make-perl locate XML::LibXSLT
```

On my LMDE box, it outputs:

```
== dh-make-perl 0.80 ==
Using cached Contents from Thu Sep 18 13:23:19 2014
XML::LibXSLT is in libxml-libxslt-perl package
```

For mapping this package name to other Linux distros, you could use [distromatch](http://enricozini.org/2011/debian/distromatch/). It also seems to support `Perl` (`CPAN`) and `Python` package names. Unfortunately, `distromatch` seems to be unmaintained and does not work out-of-the-box now. Recently I did manage to make it work well enough for translating Debian to openSUSE package names.

Answer (score 4):

Simple. Just search with the keyword. It will list all relevant packages. Then you can install the one you want.

e.g. on my ubuntu 12.04, I searched for `LibXSLT`:

```
$ aptitude search LibXSLT
p   libxml-libxslt-perl                                                           - Perl interface to the GNOME libxslt library                                             
v   libxslt-dev                                                                   -                                                                                         
p   libxslt1-dbg                                                                  - XSLT 1.0 processing library - debugging symbols                                         
p   libxslt1-dev                                                                  - XSLT 1.0 processing library - development kit                                           
i A libxslt1.1                                                                    - XSLT 1.0 processing library - runtime library                                           
p   libxsltc-java                                                                 - XSL Transformations (XSLT) compiler from Xalan-Java                                     
p   libxslthl-java                                                                - XSLT syntax highlighting                                                                
p   python-libxslt1                                                               - Python bindings for libxslt1                                                            
p   python-libxslt1-dbg                                                           - Python bindings for libxslt1 (debug extension)                                          
v   python2.7-libxslt1                                                            -                                                                                         
v   python2.7-libxslt1-dbg                                                        -
```

So, as listed above, it is quite evident that you want to install `libxml-libxslt-perl`.

Comment: Thanks for the starting point. The "quite evident", however, requires human inspection, I still don't know the module version, and I need to run this on every version of Ubuntu.

Comment: This is a poor solution. It will fail if the name of the module isn't in the name of the Perl distro (e.g. LWP::UserAgent)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to find which package provides Perl module is:

```
dh-make-perl locate XML::LibXSLT
```

You need to install **dh-make-perl** package

Answer (score 2):

As answered [by Christian Pietsch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25911504/373710) and pau4o [`dh-make-perl`](https://metacpan.org/release/DhMakePerl) can locate Debian packages that include a given perl module. The following script extracts all required modules from cpanfile, passes them to dh-make-perl and prints the corresponding Debian package:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# read perl modules as arguments or from ./cpanfile
use Module::CPANfile;
my @modules = @ARGV ? @ARGV : do {
    my $prereqs = Module::CPANfile->load->prereq_specs;
    keys %{$prereqs->{runtime}->{requires}};
};

# locate Debian packages that include these modules 
exit 1 unless @modules;
my $cmd = join ' ', 'dh-make-perl', 'locate', @modules, '2>/dev/null';
open my $fh, "-|", $cmd;
foreach (<$fh>) {
    # this ignore core packages
    # see DhMakePerl::Command::locate for details
    print "$1\t$2\n" if /(.+) is in (.+) package/;
}
```

I use it as `perldebs` to first install Perl modules as Debian modules and only fetch the rest from CPAN. The solution does not take into account version numbers yet:

```
$ sudo apt-get install `perldebs | awk '{print$2}'`
$ sudo cpanm --installdeps . --skip-satisfied
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of the Debian/Ubuntu/... package is derived from the name of the Perl distribution.

[`XML::LibXSLT`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXSLT) is part of the [`XML-LibXSLT`](https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-LibXSLT) distribution. You can find the distro name (`XML-LibXSLT`) by visiting the CPAN page for the module (first link). It's at the very top, after the name of the author.

To obtain the Debian/Ubuntu/... package name, lowercase the Perl distro name, prefix with `lib`, and suffix with `-perl`.<sup>[1]</sup> This gives us `libxml-libxslt-perl`.

---

Alternatively, you could also look for the package that provides `XML/LibXSLT.pm`.<sup>[2]</sup> One way of doing this:

```bash
apt-file search XML/LibXSLT.pm
```

---

1. As obtained using `"lib" . lc( $distro ) . "-perl"`.
2. As obtained using `( $module =~ s{::}{/}gr ) . ".pm"`.